# Connect to RDS Amazon only using SSH Key File (without password)

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-rds

I need to connect in a MySql DB allocated in an Amazon RDS.
For this, in my python  application I' ve the following command:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(
    host='<myhost>',
    user='<myuser>',
    password='<mypassword>',
    db='<mydb>')

cursor = conn.cursor()
```

for my ssh connection the only things that I've are:

- SSH Key File in ".pem" extension;
- SSH Hostname and SSH Username;

Thansk a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot connect to RDS instances via SSH. It is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to authenticate to an Amazon RDS MySQL database:

- **Using database credentials** that are defined within the database using [`CREATE USER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-user.html)
- **Using IAM credentials** to generate a temporary token that can be used to login to the database. See: [IAM Database Authentication for MySQL and PostgreSQL - Amazon Relational Database Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html)